# I need to convert xml data(Nested tags) into map in groovy?

Tags: groovy

I have some to convert to XML data into Map in groovy but If nested tags come it is converting only one stage rest of the tags ignored

```
VIF_data_Collection = vif_file_data.children().collectEntries{n->[(n.name()):{->n.children()?.collectEntries(owner)?:n.text()}()]}
```

example xmlfile:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mmVfv.png)

Comment: Please don't use screenshots, where text would do.  We can not search in
or copy from screenshots.

Comment: Can you post some actual XML, and what result you're expecting?

Comment: Please simplify your xml file and post it here as text. This would make it easier for contributors to test their ideas with your data.